# Autocomplete Jquery displaying data in wrong format

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete, visualforce

Below is the autocomplete jquery script which i am using to display data.I am getting the value in the javascript, but while displaying its not correclty dipslaying the data.

Below is the autocomplete jquery script which i am using to display data.I am getting the value in the javascript, but while displaying its not correclty dipslaying the data.

```
Data need to display is 

3 1st Ave NW
```

But displaying as

```
[
{
"
n
a
m
e
"
:"
3 
1
s
t
A
v
e 
N
W
"
}
]
```

script :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            var PLACEHOLDER = 'Enter Address Here'; 
            var movieObjects;
            var queryTerm;

            $('[id$=addressTextBox]').autocomplete({
                minLength: 2,
                source: function(request, response) {
                            queryTerm = request.term;
                            code1WebServiceCallout1.getAddress(request.term, function(result, event){
                                if(event.type == 'exception') {
                                      alert(event.message);
                                } else {
                                    // alert(JSON.stringify(result[0]));
                                    movieObjects = JSON.stringify(result);
                                        //'{\"name\":\"31st Ave NW\"}';

                                     response(movieObjects);
                                }
                            });
                       },
                focus: function( event, ui ) {
                        $('[id$=addressTextBox]').val(ui.item.name);
                        return false;
                        },
                select: function( event, ui ) {
                            $('[id$=addressTextBox]').val(ui.item.name);
                    //$('[id$=searchMovieId]').val( ui.item.Id );
                            return false;
                        },
             })
             .data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
                var entry = "<a>" + item.label;

                entry = entry + "</a>";
                entry = entry.replace(queryTerm, "<b>" + queryTerm + "</b>");
                return $( "<li></li>" )
                    .data( "item.autocomplete", item)
                    .append( entry )
                    .appendTo( ul );
            };

            // Add or remove placeholder values
            $('[id$=addressTextBox]').val(PLACEHOLDER);
            $('[id$=addressTextBox]').on("focus",  function(event){
                $tgt = $(event.target);
                if($tgt.val() === PLACEHOLDER ){
                    $tgt.val('');
                    $tgt.removeClass('placeHolder');
                }
            });
            $('[id$=addressTextBox]').on( "blur",  function(event){
                $tgt = $(event.target);
                if($tgt.val() === '' ){
                    $tgt.val(PLACEHOLDER);
                    $tgt.addClass('placeHolder');
                }
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: Where is the data coming from that way? Is it already garbled when you fetch the JSON?

Comment: I am fetching through a rest api call which i am doing at controller level.It returns like : [name=3 1st Ave NW] to the page..

Comment: Well, at which point does it show up garbled? Are you sure the problem is not already in the data source?

Comment: while debugging i saw line:  .data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {... from here the issue starts...i am sure there is no issue in data source...